# Mounting NTFS drives previous in NAS

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab, ntfs

I have 2x 3TB hard drives that were previously in a Buffalo NAS and formatted in NTFS. I want to get rid of the NAS and move the drives into an Ubuntu machine, but I'm having trouble mounting.

Steps I've taken so far:

1- Ran fdisk -l, and the output below is for the 2 drives in question. Given file size, I'm wanting to mount sdb6 and sdc6.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.75 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFRX-68E
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 88E57593-A093-4314-8F76-7973CD42794E

Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        34    2000000    1999967 976.6M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2   2000896   11999231    9998336   4.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3  11999232   12000000        769 384.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdb4  12000001   12000001          1   512B Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  12000002   14000000    1999999 976.6M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb6  14000128 5843750911 5829750784   2.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2.75 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFRX-68E
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AACC386C-088B-4795-8212-52BB14A43F6C

Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1        34    2000000    1999967 976.6M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc2   2000896   11999231    9998336   4.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc3  11999232   12000000        769 384.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdc4  12000001   12000001          1   512B Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc5  12000002   14000000    1999999 976.6M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc6  14000128 5843750911 5829750784   2.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

2- Created 2 directories, called /media/drive1 and /media/drive2

3- Tried a variety of mounting techniques along the lines of below, all giving the same output:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sdb6 /media/drive1

NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb6': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb6' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

4- I've searched a few queries and so tried

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb6
```

Which gave the output:

```
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I don't believe there is an "error" on the drives, to the extent that they were working fine this morning in the NAS. Both drives are giving identical errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated - ideally I'd like to eventually have them automounted in fstab, but at this point just getting them to mount manually would help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Linux distros have no real NTFS error correction tools (ntfsfix merely signals the drive need fixing). You need Windows for that. And for that reason don't use NTFS unless you have to (shared data partition with Windows). Preferably format them with EXT4 after backing up (via the original NAS) to somewhere else.